# How does DataManPro AppWatch get info about installed apps

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

How does AppWatch feature in [DatamanPro](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dataman-pro-track-data-usage/id572431648?mt=8) show the icon of the installed apps?

The dataman shows icons of the app that have used data in the certain interval. I believe using sysctl its able to figure out which process is using data, but how does it get the app icon?

I originally believed that its getting the icon from iTunes AppStore search url, but I found out that it does get icon for non-app store apps as well, which means that it is somehow getting that app icon locally from the iOS.